# Select as column name with quote on oracle

Tags: html, css, oracle

I insert some css script on the oracle field so that the text field can make correspond change on the web.

Note that I can't change the web so I can only using this way to change the text style.

Here is the oracle script for now, text could be change the font color now, but I try to edit column name style and I found that column name seems can not have quote character.

Is there any way to naming column with quote?

```
SELECT '<DIV style="width:150px;font-size:64px">' || A.Type || '</DIV>' AS "Type",
CASE WHEN A.ratio > 10 THEN '<DIV style="width:100px;color:Green;font-size:64px">' || A.ratio || '</DIV>'
                       ELSE '<DIV style="width:100px;color:Red;font-size:64px">' || A.ratio || '</DIV>'
END AS Rario
FROM Table A
```

Script I want:

```
SELECT '<DIV style="width:150px;font-size:64px">' || A.Type || '</DIV>' AS "<DIV style="width:150px;font-size:64px">Type</DIV>",
CASE WHEN A.ratio > 10 THEN '<DIV style="width:100px;color:Green;font-size:64px">' || A.ratio || '</DIV>'
                       ELSE '<DIV style="width:100px;color:Red;font-size:64px">' || A.ratio || '</DIV>'
END AS Rario
FROM Table A
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm):

> ... neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers can contain double
> quotation marks or the null character (\0).

I guess you could use the single quote character, but I haven't checked it.

I do not think this approach is a good idea. I think you should be putting your style elements in a different column and then adding that to the column header display.

Comment: What I want to do is transfer column name into <DIV style="width:150px;font-size:64px">Type</DIV> , but quote is not allow to show up on column name.